# running ./manage.py via supervisor

Tags: python, django, supervisord

/manage.py command using supervisor, is it possible? am I doing something wrong? The log file says that `can't find command './manage.py'`

```
[program:test3]
command=./manage.py test
directory=/var/www/my_venv
stdout_logfile=/var/log/test3.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/test3.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=600
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem, supervisor does not work with `./manage.py` for me but it works just fine with `python manage.py`

I changed `./manage.py` to `python manage.py` and everything works.

PS: I did do `chmod +x manage.py` before trying `./manage.py` for people who might think that maybe I didn't have the permissions in place.

Comment: Symlinks look to be not followed by supervisor `/var/www/myenv/bin/python` is a symlink.

Answer (score 1):

For that to work, the path `/var/www/my_venv` should have the `manage.py` script.